# NUnit Test Adapter: Group by Class broken with named test cases (VS 2012)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, nunit

Consider the following test fixture:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NUnitDemo
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FooTests
    {
        public IEnumerable<TestCaseData> FooTestCases
        {
            get
            {
                yield return new TestCaseData(1).SetName("Once");
                yield return new TestCaseData(2).SetName("Twice");
                yield return new TestCaseData(3).SetName("Thrice");

                yield return new TestCaseData(19140101).SetName("1914.01.02");
            }
        }

        [TestCaseSource("FooTestCases")]
        public void FooTest(int v)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

With the NUnit Test Adapter (2.6) on Visual Studio 2012, Test Explorer grouped by class displays the following:

[image: Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer]

A little experimentation shows that this odd behaviour is invoked when the test name contains more than one dot. In this case, the class name is incorrectly replaced with the second-last section of the test-name, split on dot.

Is there any way to work around this issue?

I have 582 test cases in my project - most of them are named, parametrised tests.

To be honest, what I really want is the ability to organise my tests by fully-qualified class and method name, then by test-case name. The NUnit GUI does this in a rather clunky way but I am looking for integration into Visual Studio.